# UITableView Cell not showing Delete Menu

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

[image: Delete option in Menu not showing]

`UITableViewCell` is not showing the "Delete" option in this popup menu. It goes to the delete condition in the code below, but it is not showing up in the menu.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    print(action)
    print(action == #selector(delete(_:)))

    if action == #selector(copy(_:)) {
        return true
    }
    if action == #selector(paste(_:)) {
        return true
    }
    if action == #selector(delete(_:)) {
        return true
    }


    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)

}
```

Comment: The `print(action)` prints out a lot more (twenty total, including delete, copy, and paste) actions, is there a reason why you're specifically asking about "Delete"?

Comment: I have to implement delete row functionality. but its not showing up in menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get cut/copy/paste by default (can block any of these by returning `false` in `canPerformAction`) but the other actions (of which you'll see a total of 20 including delete as well as other iOS standard system actions like "selectAll" and "makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft") are not included in a `UITableViewCell`'s context menu by default.

If you want any additional actions to show up you have to implement them in your `UITableViewCell` subclass.

e.g. in your cell subclass just add:

```
override func delete(_ sender: Any?) {
    print("delete")
}
```

And if you return `true` for the delete selector, you should see the delete item in the context menu for any such cell. `performAction` in the table view's delegate is still necessary, since otherwise it won't show the menu at all, but the actual handling of the action is in this cell subclass method.

If you want to add custom actions you can add them to the shared `UIMenuController` items and also implement them in the `UITableViewCell` subclass as well. (Used [this tutorial](http://www.figure.ink/blog/2015/7/12/custom-menu-items-for-table-view-cells) as a reference, as well as my own testing).

e.g. in your view controller's `viewDidLoad`

```
let menuController = UIMenuController.shared
let item = UIMenuItem(title: "My Custom Action", action: #selector("youraction"))
var items = menuController.menuItems ?? [UIMenuItem]()
items.append(item)
menuController.menuItems = items
```

Then you'd need to implement "youraction" in your `UITableViewCell` subclass or else it won't show up.

Note none of the standard 20 actions you see printed out in `canPerformAction` should need to be manually added to the shared menu controller, just looks like you need to add them to your cell subclass.

Comment: Strange, it seems that `canPerformAction` is called both before the menu is shown and just once after the menu item is pressed… (but the documentation doesn't seem to mention this behaviour). I suppose it gives a developer the chance to block an action that may have initially seemed to be permissible…? The [documentation for this delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614898-tableview) is already somewhat lousy, as it doesn't even mention that you would see other actions other than just copy/paste or how to get other ones to show…